# Check dict from Json output (urllib2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pull specific data from json output using urllib2.
From the code and output below, I am trying to pull out specific value but i didn't manage to do that.

This is the URL itself:

```
baseURIs: [
{
service: "true",
location: "alex",
URL: "barcelonat",
},
{
service: "false",
location: "daniel",
URL: "RealMadrid",
},
```

This is the output from the json (using my code):

```
{u'URL': u'barcelona', u'location': u'alex', u'service': u'true'}
{u'URL': u'RealMadrid', u'location': u'daniel', u'service': u'false'}
```

I am trying to search this dict and print "found it" if the string 'RealMadrid' is there.
Here is code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime
import json
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://admin/alex/0.json')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
user_dict = json.loads(page)
count = 0

for k in user_dict['baseURIs']:
    if 'RealMadrid' in k:
        print("Found it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code:

```
for k in user_dict['baseURIs']:
    if 'RealMadrid' in k:
        print("Found it!")
```

Searches for `'RealMadrid'` in the dictionary `k`, which means it looks for that string in the dictionary **keys**. However, in the dictionary you provided as input, `'RealMadrid'` is not a key, but the value associated with the `'URL'` key. You should replace the above with:

```
for k in user_dict['baseURIs']:
    if k['URL'] == 'RealMadrid':
        print("Found it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching inside the dict keys instead of values. Try:

```
for k in user_dict['baseURIs']:
    if 'RealMadrid' in k.values():
        print("Found it!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values to compare them with your searchterm

```
user_dict= {
    "baseURIs": [
    {
        "service": "true",
        "location": "alex",
        "URL": "barcelonat",
    },
    {
        "service": "false",
        "location": "daniel",
        "URL": "RealMadrid",
    }]
}


for key in user_dict['baseURIs']:
    if 'RealMadrid' in key.values():
        print("Found it!")
```